# Facebook login button callback

Tags: php, asp.net, facebook

Working with Facebook Login

The code is as follows,

```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-login-button"  data-width="200" onlogin="GetData()"></div>
<script>
                window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                        appId: 'My ID',
                        status: false,
                        cookie: true,
                        xfbml: true,
                        oauth: true
                });
                };        
                (function (d) {
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
                } (document));

        function GetData()
        {
        alert(11);
        }

</script>
```

1-it is working fine but the function GetData do not call after the user press facebook login button
2- I want write code in this function to give me the email,use name , ... information about this user

Comment: This isn't a site where people will just write code for you. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Call this function for facebook login your `GetData` function called after user logged .

function facebooklogin(){

```
  FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
             GetData();
        });

        }
```